# how to configure the path in .htaccess? php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How do I configure the path in `.htaccess`? Does not work in an embedded directory, works like this.

```
mysite.ru/auth/auth.php
```

(and here itself `.htaccess`) I need

```
mysite.ru/rest/auth/auth.php
```

(and here itself `.htaccess`)

`htaccess` for the working version of the 1st

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $% {ENV: BASE} auth.php [QSA, L]
```

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rest/auth/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ auth.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Good to see you on Stack Overflow, welcome to the community.   :)